# Java program freezes for 10 seconds after receiving around 1000 UDP DatagramPackets then resumes again

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have a PC running a Unity C# application sending a UDP packet each few milliseconds to other Machines via network (2 KUKA robots on windows 7 embedded and running the same JAVA program, it has an i5 Intel processor, so it's pretty powerful). 
The Java program is supposed to receive these packets, parse their content (robot positions, coded in an array of 7 values separated by '#'), move and read again. The problem is, when the PC sends packets at a rate of 1 each 0.02 secs(this doesn't happen at 0.03 or above, it is a hardware limit?!), the java program freezes at around 1000 packets received (sometimes 955 or 986, etc.) for a 8-10 seconds, then resumes again. It does the same when it arrives to 2000, and 3000.
The program freezes at :

```
serverSocket.receive(receivedPacket); // receives the array of Bytes
```

I suspected the network switch, so connected the PC directly to on robot, but nothing changed. The weird thing is, it happens at the same time for the two robots, which made me suspect the PC. But, when my colleague started a console displaying in real-time the C# program sending packets, it didn't freeze when the java programs were frozen, and looked like these packets were lost.
I looked for similar questions on SO, many suspected buffers, so I'm thinking about creating a thread that listens to the UDP port and stores packets in a queue on the memory, then my main java program reads from that thread. Does it look like a viable track to follow? 
Any suggestions are welcome.

P.S. Here's the code :

---

```
package readers;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MyProgram {
    // Network variables 
    public static DatagramSocket serverSocket;
    private static DatagramPacket receivedPacket; 

    // Received data variables
    private static byte[] aReceivedData = new byte[1024];
    private static String sReceivedData;
    private static String sAxesInformationReceived;
    private static Double[] dAxesInformationReceived = new Double[7]; 

    // ******** MAIN ***************************************
    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception {  
        int mFramecount =0;
        int mPort = 30004; //default value
        int mTimeout = 20*1000; //default value
        int mFramelimit = (15 * 1000); //default value

        // Create UDP server socket
        try {
            serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(mPort);
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.setSoTimeout(mTimeout);
        } catch (SocketException e) 
        {   System.err.println("socket bind fail"); closeSocket();e.printStackTrace(); return; }

        // Receive the UDP packet   
        try {
            receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(aReceivedData, aReceivedData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivedPacket); // receive the array of Bytes
        } catch (Exception e) { closeSocket();  return; }  
        //Clear Buffer  
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if(dAxesInformationReceived[i] == null)
            {
                dAxesInformationReceived[i] = 0.0;
            }
        }


        // <<<<<<<<<<<WHILE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 
        while (true) {          

            //Clear Buffer
            for(int i=0; i < aReceivedData.length; i++)
            {
                aReceivedData[i]=0;
            }


            // Decoding and Parsing received values
            try {

                receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(aReceivedData, aReceivedData.length); 
                serverSocket.receive(receivedPacket); // receive the array of Bytes

                byte[] byteData = new byte[receivedPacket.getLength()];
                System.arraycopy(receivedPacket.getData(), receivedPacket.getOffset(), byteData, 0,  receivedPacket.getLength()); 
                sReceivedData = new String(byteData, "UTF-8");   
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@(.*?)@"); // RegEx
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sReceivedData); 
                System.out.println("Data: '" + sReceivedData + "', || length: " + byteData.length + "|| Frame count="+ mFramecount ++);

                /*
                 * mFramecount++;
                        if (mFramecount %100 == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Data: '" + sReceivedData + "', || length: " + byteData.length + "|| Frame count="+ mFramecount );
                        }
                 */

                if (matcher.find()) {
                    sAxesInformationReceived = matcher.group(1);
                    String[] sAxesValuesInStringArray = sAxesInformationReceived.split("#");
                    if (sAxesValuesInStringArray.length != 7) {
                        System.err.println("[UnityControl] invalide number of axis");
                        break;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                        dAxesInformationReceived[i] = Double.parseDouble(sAxesValuesInStringArray[i]);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.err.println("[UnityControl] invalid format");
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("[UnityControl] socket exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }



            /* THIS PART IS USING THE ROBOT's API */
            // Change destination according to the received position
            JointPosition framePos = new JointPosition(
                    Math.toRadians(dAxesInformationReceived[0]),
                    Math.toRadians(dAxesInformationReceived[1]),
                    Math.toRadians(dAxesInformationReceived[2]),
                    Math.toRadians(dAxesInformationReceived[3]),
                    Math.toRadians(dAxesInformationReceived[4]),
                    Math.toRadians(dAxesInformationReceived[5]),
                    Math.toRadians(dAxesInformationReceived[6]));

            try {
                if(runtime.setDestination(framePos)<0) 
                    break; // break when error planning robot motion
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Runtime exeption");
                break;
            }

            if(mFramecount >= mFramelimit) break;


        }
        // LOOP BACK  
    }

    //**********************************************************************
    static void closeSocket() {
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            serverSocket.disconnect();
            serverSocket.close();
            System.out.println("[UnityControl] socket closed");

        }
    }

}
```

---

[image: screenshot]

I did what @EJP suggested in his answer, and to better track the problem, I added the number of the packet in its end, and it appears that there's a loss of the UDP packets, on both machines (The PC's log says it didn't stop sending meanwhile). Here's a log from both machines running the same code:

[image: Log two machines]

Comment: My first thought would be "garbage collection". So you could monitor your applications heap-usage using jconsole and/or activate GC-logging to see if the VMs major GCs correlate with the "freezing" of the application. If they do using a separate input-thread will be counter-productive and you need to do some GC-tuning.

Comment: Is there a way for GC-tuning? I'm no java expert

Answer (score 0):

There is high probability that problem is with you GC (Garbage Collection) that is making thing called **stop the world**. Stop the world freeze application and clean memory from not used objects :). You can obtain your program PID, then connect jconsole to see what is happening with your memory.

There is also possibility that setting more memory would help.
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
-Xms        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx        set maximum Java heap size

If you are using many threads there is possibility that creating thread is so memory and time consuming - then you can use Thread pool.

Unfortunetelly I'm not able to help you more without any code.

Comment: I was using only one Runnable launched from my program's main. The pseudo code is quite simple: 

`While (true) {
 - Wait for UDP packet  
-  Parse Values
-  Move robot to the received position
}` 

I can add the code to my question of that helps

Comment: Now, I bulked everything in the same thread, and the problem consists.

Comment: You really should post some code. It would be much easier to try figure it out.

Comment: OK. I'll try to write it on eclipse then paste it to the question, 'cause I have it on the robot's IDE (which is java with specific robotic API)

Comment: When you get too long STW-times during major GCs with a "classic" collector (mark-sweep-compact) using a larger heap would make the pause-times *longer* while using a smaller heap would make them shorter. Ths best bet would be to use a dedicated low-pause collector like CMS or G1 with a not-too-large heap.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating much more garbage than necessary. You don't need `byteArray` at all, or the `System.arraycopy()`:

```
sReceivedData = new String(receivedPacket.getData(), 0, receivedPacket.getLength(), "UTF-8");
```

You also don't need to keep recompiling the same regular expression into a `Pattern`.

You also don't need to zero the byte array prior to the receive.

NB Calling `setReuseAddress()` *after* constructing the `DatagramSocket` (and therefore binding it) is a complete waste of time.

Comment: I did what you said, but the problem still there. I added a screenshot of the log of the receiving machines on the question.

Comment: I would now point out that you certainly don't really need a `String`, a regular expression, a `Pattern`, and a `Matcher` to decode this rather simple protocol. Just process the byte array directly. Check that the expected header and trailer are there, and then just ignore them and look at what's inside.

Comment: Do you think it's an overkill? 
Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: The problem is that I ended up using other data structures to locate the values between dieses, and convert them to doubles again. 
Any idea how to do this more efficiently than with regex and strings?

Comment: It's the complete code. I tried to do what you said, by removing "String", "Pattern" and "Matcher" , but I ended up using my own decoding algorithm, that would use also Data structures to store,iterate on the received array and convert them to Doubles so the robot can move.
Is there anyway I can retrieve the Double values from the bytes array (they are separated by dieses), in a way more optimized than my first one?